# How to use ng-repeat for dictionaries in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, json, dictionary, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know that we can easily use *ng-repeat* for json objects or arrays like:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users"></div>
```

but how can we use the ng-repeat for dictionaries, for example:

```
var users = null;
users["182982"] = "{...json-object...}";
users["198784"] = "{...json-object...}";
users["119827"] = "{...json-object...}";
```

I want to use that with users dictionary:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users"></div>
```

Is it possible?. If yes, how can I do it in AngularJs?

Example for my question:
In C# we define dictionaries like:

```
Dictionary<key,value> dict = new Dictionary<key,value>();

//and then we can search for values, without knowing the keys
foreach(var val in dict.Values)
{
}
```

Is there a build-in function that returns the values from a dictionary like in c#?

Comment: What is the difference between a dictionary and a JSON object? I believe there is none in javascript!

Comment: @markmarijnissen: [A JSON object has more stringent syntax rules than a JavaScript object](http://json.org/). And, as we’re already in Pedant’s Corner, there’s no such thing as a “Dictionary” in JavaScript. We just call them objects.

Answer (score 564, accepted):

You can use

```
<li ng-repeat="(name, age) in items">{{name}}: {{age}}</li>
```

See [ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WRtqV/1/

Comment: This is not what I asked but exacly what I wanted. Thank you Artem Andreev

Comment: How can we use filter in this ng-repeat. Its not working in my case when i am using a search filter. Say <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" /><li ng-repeat="(name, age) in items | filter:searchText ">{{name}}: {{age}}</li>...

Comment: @Shekhar Filter "filter" works only with arrays. You can try to create feature request.

Comment: Good to see some commonality with python :)

Comment: The problem I'm running into is editing age, for example. I find that doing an ng-repeat this way & then binding name, age to input elements makes them non-editable. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495749/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-key-value-updating-object)

Comment: You can get filter feature even on dictionaries(objects) by using the ng-if statement.. like for example: <li ng-repeat="(id, obj) in items" ng-if='obj.sex="female"'>{{obj.name}} {{obj.surname}}</li>  ... where items is a set of persons indexed by some key.

Comment: @giowild -- **Thanks!** I'm not sure why angular doesn't natively allow a `filter` (or `orderBy`) on object `ng-repeat`. But the `ng-if` worked great! I wish there was a way to do `orderBy` as well in the view. I get that properties are alphabetical and it orders by the property name, but it would be nice to have the option to order by something else as well.

Comment: to clarify the bracketed parameters are the key and value (in that order): `<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>`

Comment: One problem of this approach is that (at least in Angular 1.2) it sorts key-value pairs by key. So it won't display the items in the order they are in e.g. object literal. For some (most?) use cases it's actually a useful feature though.

Comment: Use [toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) to enable orderBy on objects.

Answer (score 27):

I would also like to mention a new functionality of [AngularJS `ng-repeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat), namely, special repeat **start** and **end points**. That functionality was added in order to repeat a *series* of HTML elements instead of just a *single* parent HTML element.

In order to use repeater start and end points you have to define them by using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives respectively.

The `ng-repeat-start` directive works very similar to `ng-repeat` directive. The difference is that is will repeat **all** the HTML elements (including the tag it's defined on) up to the ending HTML tag where `ng-repeat-end` is placed (including the tag with `ng-repeat-end`).

**Sample code (from a controller):**

```
// ...
$scope.users = {};
$scope.users["182982"] = {name:"John", age: 30};
$scope.users["198784"] = {name:"Antonio", age: 32};
$scope.users["119827"] = {name:"Stephan", age: 18};
// ...
```

**Sample HTML template:**

```
<div ng-repeat-start="(id, user) in users">
    ==== User details ====
</div>
<div>
    <span>{{$index+1}}. </span>
    <strong>{{id}} </strong>
    <span class="name">{{user.name}} </span>
    <span class="age">({{user.age}})</span>
</div>

<div ng-if="!$first">
   <img src="/some_image.jpg" alt="some img" title="some img" />
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>
    ======================
</div>
```

Output would look similar to the following (depending on HTML styling):

```
==== User details ====
1.  119827 Stephan (18)
======================
==== User details ====
2.  182982 John (30)
[sample image goes here]
======================
==== User details ====
3.  198784 Antonio (32)
[sample image goes here]
======================
```

As you can see, `ng-repeat-start` repeats all HTML elements (including the element with `ng-repeat-start`). All `ng-repeat` special properties (in this case `$first` and `$index`) also work as expected.

Comment: Error: [$compile:uterdir] Unterminated attribute, found 'ng-repeat-start' but no matching 'ng-repeat-end' found.

Comment: @zloctb you must have skipped `<div ng-repeat-end>..</div>` in your markup

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript developers tend to refer to the above data-structure as either an object or hash instead of a Dictionary.

Your syntax above is wrong as you are initializing the `users` object as null.  I presume this is a typo, as the code should read:

```
// Initialize users as a new hash.
var users = {};
users["182982"] = "...";
```

To retrieve all the values from a hash, you need to iterate over it using a for loop:

```
function getValues (hash) {
    var values = [];
    for (var key in hash) {

        // Ensure that the `key` is actually a member of the hash and not
        // a member of the `prototype`.
        // see: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#for%20statement
        if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            values.push(key);
        }
    }
    return values;
};
```

If you plan on doing a lot of work with data-structures in JavaScript then the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library is definitely worth a look.  Underscore comes with a [`values` method](http://underscorejs.org/#values) which will perform the above task for you:

```
var values = _.values(users);
```

I don't use Angular myself, but I'm pretty sure there will be a convenience method build in for iterating over a hash's values (ah, there we go, Artem Andreev provides the answer above :))

Comment: +1 for underscore.js and these useful informations. Thank You Johnny!

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 7, the following simple example would work (assuming dictionary is in a variable called `d`):

my.component.ts:

```
keys: string[] = [];  // declaration of class member 'keys'
// component code ...

this.keys = Object.keys(d);
```

my.component.html:  (will display list of key:value pairs)

```
<ul *ngFor="let key of keys">
    {{key}}: {{d[key]}}
</ul>
```