# How can I use ng-repeat to iterate over an array's objects attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got an array with objects similar to:

```
{
    _id:       "0",
    category: "ptr",
    price:    14.5
}
```

So I'm printing an **HTML table** this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products.categoryQuery">
    <td>{{product._id}}</td>
    <td>{{product.category}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Being `queryCategory` an array with my objects. I wonder if I can reduce the HTML and add an **`ng-repeat`** **directive** at a `<td>` for iterating over object's attributes.

I tried:

```
<td ng-repeat"p for p in product">{{p}}</td>
```

and

```
<td ng-repeat"p for p in product">{{product[p]}}</td>
```

But got not results. How could I achieve it?

### Edit.

As critics suggest, there's this alternative when it's got **one single object**:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

But how can I use it when they're several objects from an array?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, in that case I got one single object and here I got an array with objects.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to iterate over an object's properties. Whether it's in an array or not makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the responses in this question: [How to use ng-repeat for dictionaries in AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985863/how-to-use-ng-repeat-for-dictionaries-in-angularjs)

Essentially you should be able to follow the `(k, v) in expression` syntax (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat in the Arguments section)

The one thing I would say is that the order of the keys might not be in the order you expect, which could cause issues: [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop/280861#280861)