# In angularjs how do I iterate through JSON to fill in values when I don't have a key value?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data structure:

```
{
"0": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
},
"1": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
},
"2": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
},
"3": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
},
"4": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
},
"5": {
"keyword": "lawn",
"short_desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
"pt_value": "10"
}
}
```

I need to run ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="SOMETHING">
        <p>{{ desc }}</p>
        <p>{{ points }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I can run something as simple as ng-repeat="product as products" so how can I iterate through the data, repeat, and place content where I need it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11986277/893113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [syntax of ng-repeat expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#arguments), you could still manage the repeat with an object.

Provided scope.items represent the object in the question:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="(k, item) in items">
        <p>{{ item.short_desc}}</p>
        <p>{{ item.pt_value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.