# How to use ng-repeat for nested dictionaries in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the value is itself an object. I want to show the entries in a table using `ng-repeat`.

Here is the dictionary:

```
{
        'adam': {
            c1: "a",
            c2: "b"
        },
        'amalie': {
            c1: "c",
            c2: "d"
        }
    };
```

I have visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11985863/848377) question but it talks about simple key-value pairs.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dh0d8nd/1/).

I want it to be shown as:

```
NAME c1 c2
adam a b
amalie c d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(name, ages) in items">              
        {{name}} 
        <span ng-repeat="age in ages">
            {{age}}
        </span>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dh0d8nd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(name, age) in items">{{name}}: {{age.c1}} : {{age.c2}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

use like this...

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated jsFiddle. Hope this helps.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>C2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="(name, age) in items">
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{age.c1}}</td>
            <td>{{age.c2}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dh0d8nd/2/

Answer (score 0):

It can be like this:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table style="width:50%">
         <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>C1</th>
            <th>C2</th>
         </tr>   
         <tr ng-repeat="(name,age) in items">
            <td>{{name}} </td>
            <td> {{age.c1}}</td>        
            <td> {{age.c2}}</td>
         </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<table style="width:100%">

</table>
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dh0d8nd/5/).