# Angular translate : repeat on json object

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a json file like this :

```
{
    "pages": {
        "page1": {
            "field1": "....",
            "field2": "....",
            "field3": "....",
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "illustration": "images/img.png",
                    "content": "...."
                },
                {
                    "illustration": "images/img.png",
                    "content": "...."
                },
                {
                    "illustration": "images/img.png",
                    "content": "...."
                }
            ]
        },
        ......
```

When i want to use it in my html, i just do :
`{{ 'pages.page1.field1' | translate }}` for example

BUT

What if i need to repeat ? For thumbnails.

```
<div ng-repeat="thumbnail in pages.page1.thumbnails">
      {{ thumbnail.content }}
</div>
```

But obviously it's not working. I don't know how to access thumbnails.

*EDIT 1 :*

I'm using "useStaticFilesLoader" like this in my config :

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'assets/app_components/app/languages/emag_',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

So i don't have a json defined into my controller.

*EDIT 2* : 
To be more precise, here's a plunkr with what i exactly want to do : To help you understand what's my problem, i made a little plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/mocztnQYvmmuc3Nslmnb?p=preview

Comment: Your thumbnails property is not an array. You should fix your JSON-file to get it work. There is nothing wrong with your HTML code as far as I can see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ng-repeat for dictionaries in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985863/how-to-use-ng-repeat-for-dictionaries-in-angularjs)

Comment: @Julien, i don't think my problem is the same here.  
I don't know how to access a json object automatically loaded from angular translate "useStaticFilesLoader".

Comment: @ABr, you and Mikos are rights. I changed my json file but still ... How to access the json object coming from angular translate "useStaticFilesLoader" ? I would need something like this :   
<div ng-repeat="thumbnail in {{ 'pages.page1.thumbnails' | translate }}">

Comment: To help you understand what's my problem, i made a little plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/mocztnQYvmmuc3Nslmnb?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You have bad json file.You have objects in object. You need array.

Try this.

```
{
"thumbnails": [
    {
        "illustration": "images/img.png",
        "content": "...."
    },
    {
        "illustration": "images/img.png",
        "content": "...."
    },
    {
        "illustration": "images/img.png",
        "content": "...."
    }
]
```

}

I think that ng-repeat works only with array because ng-repeat need know lenght.

Sry for bad english :)

Pages same problem.

```
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "fields": [
                "...",
                "...",
                "...."
            ],
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "illustration": "image/img_01.png",
                    "content": "...."
                },
                {
                    "illustration": "image/img_01.png",
                    "content": "...."
                },
                {
                    "illustration": "image/img_01.png",
                    "content": "...."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Damn. I'm tired, you're right ! I changed it like you said, but in fact i don't think ng-repeat can access json file directly. At least, my code is not working. 
``<div ng-repeat="vignette in pages.page1.vignettes" .....``  
I do not have a controller which contains a json object pages. It is automatically loaded from angular translate (see "EDIT 1").

Comment: I never use **useStaticFilesLoader** but your json have bad structure. u need this `<div ng-repeat="thumb in pages[1].thumbnails">... ` or  `<div ng-repeat="vignettein pages[1].vignettes">... `

Comment: Yes, as i said in my previous comment, i edited my JSON just as you said. With an array. Now that my json is correct, how can i do ?

Comment: if you need know that your app have access to some position in JSON just type {{pages[1]}} then add {{pages[1].thumbnails}} i need url of first thumb {{pages[1].thumbnails[1].url}} :) and check your results :) [link](http://www.json-generator.com/) here check your JSON

Comment: To help you understand what's my problem, i made a little plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/mocztnQYvmmuc3Nslmnb?p=preview

Comment: Oh ok its look like that useStaticFilesLoader can't read arrays (can't read JSON)... Its convert to same constants or what is it. (NAMESPACE.SUBNAMESPACE.HEADLINE) it is `"NAMESPACE" : {"SUBNAMESPACE": {"HEADLINE": "Text here...", "SUBHEADLINE": "Text here.."}}`... I try some "hack" for this but u need know count of thumbnails. Create controller and use **$translate** then you can use `$translate('YOUR_CONSTANT').then(function (translation) { "this code return promisse" });`

Comment: Here is plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/TRN2xKbyOQTOce0Bq7Ou?p=preview ... but this is realy not good practise... Use translate only for Static texts like buttons, placeholders, etc... Other text call from database like `/restAPI/page/1?lang=en`

Comment: Wait for better programmer, I'm novice in angular (15 days) I don't know what is best practice.