# Getting value from complex JSON array in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have `JSON` array look like this

```
{
    "-K3OFVYXVUiT-oYXFmgX": {
        "id": 4658,
        "username": "shamon"
    },
    "-K3OFZAt9Qyy9v6z-XYQ": {
        "id": 9891,
        "username": "manu"
    },
    "-K3OFafyCi6g9UhdR2mA": {
        "id": 7219,
        "username": "hari"
    },
    "-K3OGYGGry3pU8_Qkjg_": {
        "id": 8028,
        "username": "shamonsha"
    }
}
```

I want to display the usernames in a `<ul>` list

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in userlist">{{user.username}}</li>
<ul>
```

But I will get empty result

**UPDATE**

Here is my full code,its a response  form firebase url,the problem is i will get `console.log($scope.userlist)` but it will not updated in html list

```
.controller('chatCtrl',function($scope){
    messagesRef= new Firebase(chaturl+'userlist');
        messagesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                  var  msg= snapshot.val();
               $scope.userlist=JSON.stringify(msg);
               console.log($scope.userlist);
            });
});
```

Comment: Related: [How to use ng-repeat for dictionaries in AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985863/how-to-use-ng-repeat-for-dictionaries-in-angularjs)

Comment: `user` will likely be assigned each key (`"-K3OFVYXVUiT-oYXFmgX"`, etc.) rather than each value in `userlist`. You can verify this by outputting `{{typeof user}}` (the key is a string, the value is an object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(key, value) in expression`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in userlist">
        {{value.username}}
    </li>
<ul>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qcx2g9yg/)</kbd>

EDIT: Need to use `$scope.$apply(fn)` so that changes is updated.

```
.controller('chatCtrl',function($scope){
    messagesRef= new Firebase(chaturl+'userlist');
    messagesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
              var  msg= snapshot.val();
              $scope.$apply(function () { 
                   $scope.userlist=JSON.stringify(msg); 
              });
        });
});
```

Comment: @BlessanKurien, May be you need `$scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.userlist=JSON.stringify(msg);
        });`

Comment: Where can i place it? inside `messageRef.on`