# How to get nested JSON data by using ng repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to getting items._id value in ng view by using ng-repeat.
occurring all data but i want specific data.

data.json

```
 [ { _id        : "td6v9db4514cc4ewew4334",
     firstName  : 'ayaz',
     lastName   : 'memon',
     items      : '[{"_id":"item2","_name":"My Item #4"},
                    {"_id":"item3","_name":"My Item #4"}]',
     totalItems :  3,
     totalPrice :  2999.97 } ]
```

Controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("data.json").then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)

    $scope.userInfo = response.data
  })
})
```

ng view

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="x in userInfo">
  <li >{{x}}</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat="item in x.items"` will return each item

Comment: You will have to use nested `ng-repeat`.

Comment: The data you show is not valid JSON. Keys in JSON have to be surrounded by `"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ng-repeat for dictionaries in AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985863/how-to-use-ng-repeat-for-dictionaries-in-angularjs)

Comment: check out this http://plnkr.co/edit/6jTrwMKdLDcH5T3ZFiS7?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using nested json object ie items in userInfo, you can write ng-repeat as,

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in userInfo.items">{{x._id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Note: It will be good to understand if you use ng-repeat in `<li></li>` instead of `<ul></ul>`

Comment: Just a minor problem, `userInfo` is an array of object and not object.

Comment: Yes I'm agree with you, but its single element in array so we can use like userInfo[0]

Comment: Or its just a sample input and actual data consist of *n* objects.

Comment: `<ul>`
  `<li ng-repeat="x in userInfo.items">{{x._id}}</li>`
`</ul>` 
It's not working, if i remove .items then it's giving me specific output, but not giving me items result

Comment: Try this,

<ul ng-repeat="x in userInfo">
  <li ng-repeat="y in x" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in y.items">{{item._id}}</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   [{
    "_id": "td6v9db4514cc4ewew4334",
    "firstName": "ayaz",
    "lastName": "memon",
    "items": [{
            "_id": "item2",
            "_name": "My Item #4"
        },
        {
            "_id": "item3",
            "_name": "My Item #4"
        }
    ],
    "totalItems": 3,
    "totalPrice": 2999.97
}]
```

and you could get your repeated "_id" in the items now in ng-repeat="item in userInfo.items" and with {{item._id}} .

Please correct me if there's any mistake, I'm still new.
Thanks.

Comment: How is this: `"items"      : {"_id":"item2","_name":"My Item #4"},
                    {"_id":"item3","_name":"My Item #4"},` a valid JSON?

Comment: @Rajesh you're right, I overlooked it. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: When you change something in your answer, please check if rest of it actually is in sync with update. Pointing to *this is not a nested JSON.*

Comment: @NomanKt Like I mentioned earlier, it was your JSON format, check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/eb1LCy0YqPDFlwXLci4c?p=preview , I just changed your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested ng-repeat like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in userInfo">
  <li ng-repeat="x in user.items">{{x._id}} : {{x._name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I'm assuming your http call will return a valid response because the Json data you've given is invalid. The keys need to be in enclosed within  " ". I've also structured the the ng-repeat assuming that your response will have multiple objects

Comment: there is nothing appearing

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in userInfo">
     <ul>
       {{user._id}}
       <li ng-repeat="item in user.items">
         {{item._id}}
       </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Plunker Example:** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/hzWdj2IiUI2RytYVUI7m?p=preview

Comment: Something wrong with your JSON Data, coz as you can see in my Plunker example I have used the same object as yours and it worked.

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to retrieve string as an object that was a mistake. I used object data instead of string and got result.